# jsp POST request and @RequestParam in controller giving HTTP 400 syntactically incorrect error:

Tags: java, jsp, rest, post

I have a post request in a jsp file:

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:8081/MerchantMovieTheater/api/movieTheater">
    <input type="hidden" name="balance" id="balance" value="${balance}"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Merchant Site">
</form>
```

The corresponding controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "movieTheater", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitTransaction(Model model, @RequestParam("balance") Double balance){
}
```

But when I am executing the jsp, I am getting the following error:

```
HTTP Status 400:  The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (Required Double parameter 'balance' is not present).
```

Can you please point out to me where I am going wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved! I was missing a '?' at the end of the url. The action should be:

```
action="http://localhost:8081/MerchantMovieTheater/api/movieTheater?">
```

Now everything is working fine!