# POST request to RESTful API always results in HTTP 400 Syntactically incorrect error message

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I've implemented a RESTful API in my web server using Jersey to handle simple `POST` requests.

The method is given below: -

```
@Path("create")
public class Create {

.........

@POST
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public StatusResponse createPost(
            @PathParam("id") final String identifier,
                                                 final PostInfo postInfo) {

        // Does its work 

    }
```

And following is the **PostInfo.java** : -

```
    public class PostInfo {

        private String message;
        private String date;

        public PostInfo() {

            message = null;
            date = null;

        }

        /**
         * @return the message
         */
        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        /**
         * @return the date
         */
        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        /**
         * @param message the message to set
         */
        public void setMessage(final String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        /**
         * @param date the date to set
         */
        public void setDate(final String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }

  }
```

Problem here is, every time I make a POST request with JSON elements, it results in

```
HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

I had a look at a few others posts having similar problem ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527402/jsp-post-request-and-requestparam-in-controller-giving-http-400-syntactically-i) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208682/the-request-sent-by-the-client-was-syntactically-incorrect-spring-restclie)), but they were of no help.

I'm using Chrome's POSTMan to make the request at the following URL with the following body:

URL: `wallpostapi.herokuapp.com/webapi/create/xyz123@123.com`
Body :

```
{
    "message"   :   "WHADDUP DAWG???"
    "date"      :   "2016-09-09 11:00:20"
}
```

Comment: I'm NOT using SpringMVC. I have clearly mentioned Jersey as I am using

Comment: Easy: add `,` after `"message"   :   "WHADDUP DAWG???"`. Your JSON is not correct

Comment: Good Lord!! Yes!! That was the problem.. Silly me.. Overlooked it completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of your JSON is not correct, a comma missing. Please try the following JSON.

```
{
    "message": "WHADDUP DAWG???",
    "date": "2016-09-09 11:00:20"
}
```

Further, the best practice is to use nouns but no verbs in the URI like,

```
http://wallpostapi.herokuapp.com/webapi/v1/info
```

The ID can be send in the header as an optional parameter or can be auto generated for create.

```
id   xyz123@123.com
```

The name of your create method should be,

```
public StatusResponse createInfo(
            @HeaderParam("id") final String identifier,
            final PostInfo  postInfo {
        // Does its work 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

BTW: the HTTP specifikation descripes a POST to create an subentry of an list. So the POST should go to the uri wallpostapi.herokuapp.com/webapi/create

if you know the id you should use the PUT Method of HTTP